# How do I trigger a real error in Socket.io?

Tags: reactjs, error-handling, socket.io

I am trying to decide what to do to handle errors in my chat application using Socket.io and react. I can successfully get a 'connect_error' error so I can do something inside the `socket.on('connect_error', ()=> //Do something)` but I am having trouble getting any other type of error. I can't think of a scenario where I can modify the app or do something specific to trigger the `socket.on('error', ()=> //Do something)`. Does anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

The 'error' event is not a specific one. It's by design, so ANY error event will trigger it. What you can do is console.log it.

So now, anytime you'll be able trigger any error (Which is what you want) you'll see its description, then you can google it and then write a more specific code to handle it.

If you can't trigger any errors no matter what you do, it's not a bad thing since it means things works correctly.

```
 socket.on('error', (error) => {
   console.log(error);
 });
```